# Wait for loop next iteration untill a condition is met in while loop

Tags: java

I am trying to write a condition in for loop,

```
  for (int i = 0; i < programs.size(); i++) {
    String status = "";
    ...
    String jobId = invokeAPI(userId, data); // RPC call
    while (!status.equals("DONE")) {
        if (status.equals("EXIT")) {
            break;
        }
        status = invokeAPI(jobId); // RPC Call
        Thread.sleep(60000);
    }
}
```

When status is `DONE` then increment the `for-loop` counter. In current implementation after `Thread.sleep` it starts execution from first line with 0th index.

How to modify this section so that the for-loop counter will increment once status is `DONE`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using while, but make sure you update the value of jobId :

```
int i = 0;
while(i<programs.size()){
        String status = "";
        String jobId = invokeAPI(userId, data); // RPC call
        if (status.equals("DONE")) {
            i++;
        } else {
            // i'm not sure how would you like to update the jobId othewise you will always hav same status diffrent
            //than DONE
            while (!status.equals("DONE")) {
                if (status.equals("EXIT")) {
                    break;
                }
                status = invokeAPI(jobId); // RPC Call
                Thread.sleep(60000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: when `i` is incremented a RPC is made to generate the jobid

Comment: and for that `i-th` element it will checks whether status is DONE/EXIT. Then only increment `i` and do RPC call again

Comment: inside the while you are calling, status = invokeAPI(jobId); with the same id always, the program will stuck

Comment: on `0` index we will get jobid (RPC call) so for loop won't increment to index `1`(to get next jobid) unless index `0` status is DONE (to get status again RPC call)